# What is the customary start-up steps for using git on a new machine and existing repo?

Tags: git, powershell, github, git-clone, github-for-windows

What's the standard start-up process: git init + git clone or should git clone do the init for us?

I have been using git in my workplace, and now one of my co-workers wants to start looking at my code.

I have been using the GitHub for Windows (G4W) posh-git PowerShell to run my git commands (not the GUI and not using www.github.com).  My co-worker has also installed G4W, and I am leading them via the CLI rather than the GUI.

When I went to help them get started, I made a new folder, opened our posh-git shell that comes with G4W, and did a git clone from our repo on the network share.

After that I did a git status, and posh-git was not recognizing the folder as a local git repo.

I then did a git init on the folder, and it seems OK, but I'm wondering why git clone did not effectively make the folder a repo?

Searching the web for git docs and how-to, I haven't seen anything that says I should do git init before git clone.

What is the right order or is there a correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `git clone remote://git-repo/url`. You do not need to initialize anything if you can clone.

Note that having a remote URL that ends in something like "reponame.git" will create a new directory named "reponame" in which the repository will be created, NOT the directory you are currently in.

So if you run `git status` right after `git clone`, you are in the wrong directory, you have to `cd` into it first.

Comment: in the G4W / enterprise world, I did: created folder for the local repo, cd to that folder, then `git clone file:///\\path\to\network\share` (not .git at the end), then did `git status` which returned "not a git repo" approximately.  After that all, I did the `git init` and repo came alive. Any ideas?  Will it be broken?

Comment: Explained in my answer. Have a look at where the repo really is. It's not in the current directory. You can influence the directory name by using `git clone repo://url targetdir`.

Comment: The clone command will tell you: `Cloning into 'foobar'...` is the first line after the command, and this is the directory name you either set yourself, or that was generated from the repo url.

Comment: Just checked folders on co-worker's box - you are correct, there is an extra folder `...\localfolder\myrepo\myrepo\source-files` etc.  So clearly after `git clone` `...\localfolder\myrepo\` was *not* and *should not be* the git repo.  Thanks.

Comment: Solution is to run `git clone file:///\path\to\repo` from parent folder (and not to manually create the folder that ultimately receives the cloned repo. Thanks.